# Servlet Config Parameter returning null value

Tags: java, servlets

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ServletContext context=request.getServletContext();

    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    if(userName!=""&&userName!=null){
    session.setAttribute("savedUserName",userName);
    context.setAttribute("savedUserName",userName);
    }
    write.println("Request parameter has username as "+userName);
    write.println("Session parameter has username as "+session.getAttribute("savedUserName"));
    write.println("Context parameter has username as "+context.getAttribute("savedUserName"));
    write.println("Init parameter has default username as "+ getServletConfig().getInitParameter("defaultName"));
```

This is my java servlet code in which I am trying to print servlet config parameter value passed through following web.xml file.

```
<display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
<servlet><servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>myservletpackage.XmlServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>defaultName</param-name>
<param-value>Chris Jordan</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/xmlServletPath</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But on running the config parameter value comes null.Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You spelled default wrong in the XML.

Comment: I mistakingly pasted the old code.I had already corrected the spelling.It is still not displaying the value in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added your init parameters **while the Web Container/Server was running**? Restart the server, if its already running.

Quote from "Head First Servlets & JSP" book.

> The servlet init parameters are read only **ONCE** - when the Container
>   initializes the servlet. ... When the Container makes a servlet, it
>   reads the DD and creates the name/value pairs for the ServletConfig.
>   The Container **never** reads the init parameters again! Once the
>   parameters are in the ServletConfig, they won’t be read again
>   **until/unless you redeploy** the servlet.